# hasMany Data is not Loading

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to load a parent record that contains two hasMany child records. Here are my models (I'm using ember-app-kit by the way with the latest canary of ember and ember-data):

```
var Route = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    description: DS.attr(),
    creation: DS.attr(),
    modified: DS.attr(),
    active: DS.attr(),
    adhoc: DS.attr(),
    routeUsers: DS.hasMany('user'),
    userApprovals: DS.hasMany('userApproval')
});

export default Route;

var UserApproval = DS.Model.extend({
    user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
    amount: DS.attr(),
    approval: DS.attr(),
    comment: DS.attr(),
    denyRedirect: DS.belongsTo('user')
});

export default UserApproval;

var User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstname: DS.attr(),
    lastname: DS.attr(),
    username: DS.attr(),
    email: DS.attr(),

    fullName: function(){
        return this.get('firstname') + ' ' + this.get('lastname');
    }.property('firstname', 'lastname')
});

export default User;
```

Here is the JSON that is returned from my mongodb instance:

```
{
  "route": {
    "name": "4",
    "description": "123",
    "adhoc": true,
    "_id": "527822dee56a06dc2a000002",
    "__v": 0,
    "user_approvals": [
      {
        "amount": "22",
        "user_id": "5277ca37b900b14c0e000003",
        "deny_redirect_id": "5277ca25b900b14c0e000002",
        "id": "f0ced142-aee1-4abb-f36a-56ae0088141b"
      }
    ],
    "route_users": [
      {
        "firstname": "first",
        "lastname": "last",
        "username": "flast",
        "email": "flast@xyz.com",
        "id": "5277ca37b900b14c0e000003"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my route serializer:

```
import ApplicationSerializer from 'appkit/serializers/application';

var RouteSerializer = ApplicationSerializer.extend({
    attrs: {
        routeUsers: {
            embedded: 'always'
        },
        userApprovals: {
            embedded: 'always'
        }
    }
});

export default RouteSerializer;
```

I am doing a normalization in the application serializer for the _id which is why I am extending my route serializer off of it. That is the only change in my application serializer.

The issue I am having is that when my route model gets loaded and set in my controller, none of the hasMany relations are there. When I look at my model using the ember chrome extension and the console it looks like this:

```
adhoc: true
description: "something here"
id: "527948268a65b92022000001"
name: "14"
routeUserIds: Array[1]
 0: "5277ca25b900b14c0e000002"
 length: 1
 __proto__: Array[0]
routeUsers: undefined
userApprovalIds: Array[1]
 0: "017b4fe7-9f98-4bce-9c8d-089309b7729a"
 length: 1
 __proto__: Array[0]
userApprovals: undefined
v: 0
__proto__: Object
```

So I know my route is being placed in the model, I can render things such as the name and description but nothing is there for my hasMany relations. How can I access my hasMany relations? I can look at the store and see that my hasMany relations are being loaded into the store after the payload is delivered. I have tried overriding the extractSingle with this:

```
extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
        var userApprovals = payload.route.user_approvals,
            approvalIds = userApprovals.mapProperty('id');

        payload.user_approvals = userApprovals;
        payload.route.user_approvals = approvalIds;

        return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
```

But it renders the exact same result as before with no hasMany info loaded, just the ids.

I been searching for the past couple of days and got pointed towards this PR:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1404

But I still can't get it to work. I'm sure I'm missing something, just probably need some other eyes to look.

Thanks,
Jarred

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by completely moving away from ember-data for the time being. I instead implemented ember-model which works well out of the box for my situation. I am using mongodb and a lot of embedded records. I know this doesn't fully answer the question but I am needing to close it since I am no longer in need of an answer to my original question due to the move to ember-model.

If you are experiencing the same issue with ember-data and want to know about my setup please send me a message.

-Jarred

Answer (score 0):

First, `attrs` is a straight string-to-string mapping of old key to new key, so your current use is invalid.

This exact situation is explained in detail in the TRANSITION.md document, which I am quoting below:

```
{
  "post": {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Rails is omakase",
    "comments": [{
      "id": "1",
      "body": "I like omakase"
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "body": "I prefer not to rely on elitist chefs"
    }]
  }
}
```

You could handle embedded records like this:

```
App.PostSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    var comments = payload.post.comments,
        commentIds = comments.mapProperty('id');

    payload.comments = comments;
    payload.post.comments = commentIds;

    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```